# How to stop highlighting using QgsHighlight?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

I am highlighting certain features of a layer using [QgsHighlight](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/gui/QgsHighlight.html).
On a certain event, I would like to stop the highlighting and highlight something else or nothing at all. I have tried QgsHighlight.dropEvent(), QgsHighlight.updateCanvas() or just to refresh the whole canvas but that won't help and I don't see anything else in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the logic outside `QgsHighlight` class as you can hide the highlight with `hide` method inherited from -> [QgsMapCanvasItem](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsMapCanvasItem.html) -> [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QGraphicsItem.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.hide). An illustrated sample code below:

```py
from time import sleep

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feature = next(layer.getFeatures())

color = QColor(Qt.red)
hgl1 = QgsHighlight(canvas, feature, layer)
hgl1.setColor(color)
color.setAlpha(50)
hgl1.setFillColor(color)
# Zoom to feature (just to ease debugging in the sample)
layer.selectByIds([feature.id()])
iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
layer.removeSelection()

# Start highlight
hgl1.show()
# Simulate an action with sleep. You add your custom code here
sleep(8)
hgl1.hide()
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use this code:

```
iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(highlight)
```